# Checking a co-ordinate is in the given polygon of google map

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, google-maps-api-2

I have created a polygon on google map with predefined coordinated. I want to add a validation in my web service that it should answer to those users who belongs to the above predefined polygon.
For doing so, I am getting the geological location of user but how can I check that whether this location is inside the polygon or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use containsLocation() from the geometry library of  Google Maps API ([doc here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)) :

HTML (note libraries=geometry):

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
         async defer></script>
```

Javascript:

```
// e: your point
// polygon: a Google Map Polygon
if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, polygon) {
   ...
}
```